# An error occured During creation of phonegap android sub project

Tags: android, cordova, jscript, nms

I am trying to build a `phonegap android`,At that time i got a message that

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during craetion of android sub-projesct. creating cordova project for the android platform
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have ANT installted and configured with correct path?

Comment: I have installed ANT & configured the correct path,but also the same error occurs...

Comment: You find a solution yet? : / I am having this issue right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems ant binary missing in your path!
In you install ant with npm like:

`sudo npm install -g ant`

Then just make symlink to bin folder what found in your $PATH like

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ant/ant/bin/ant /usr/local/bin/ant`

Answer (score 2):

There may be one of following two reasons-

1) .cordova directory already exists on your machine in your user folder. Delete it and try your command.

2)You have xcopy.exe somewhere on your machine. You should be able to add %SystemRoot%\System32 to your PATH.
or You can find it by running 'where xcopy' in your terminal window. XCOPY on the path is a requirement for setting up and installing Android

You need to define XCOPY on your path as it is used by the internal node.js scripts to move things around.

One of these should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with cordova 3.3.1 and phonegap 3.3.0. Finally, I opened Android SDK manager and found out `Platform tools` were outdated, though I had the latest version from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). After update, this error was gone

Answer (score 1):

Run the "android" command from your adt\sdk\tools folder and install the latest Tools and SDK. Also make sure your PATH has the right variables.

For this you will need ANT to be installed , a JAVA JDK and an Android SDK installed

JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk)

ANT_HOME ({ant location}\apache\apache-ant)

ANDROID_HOME ({android sdk location}\android-sdk)

Add these to your PATH variable like %ANT_HOME%/bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Close and re-open your cmd and run your command again.

Similiar to [PhoneGap/Cordova Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development/21613524#21613524)