# An error occured during creation of android sub-project

Tags: java, android, cordova

Trying to install phonegap on Linux Mint.

The following is occuring:

> psukardi@psukardi-XPS-M1530 ~/Development/my-app $ phonegap run
>   android [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment... [phonegap]
>   using the local environment [phonegap] adding the Android platform... 
>   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
>
> /home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
>       at /home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
>       at _rejected (/home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
>       at /home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
>       at Promise.when (/home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
>       at /home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
>       at flush (/home/psukardi/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
>
> psukardi@psukardi-XPS-M1530 ~/Development/my-app $

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem, and I found it was a duplicate of [PhoneGap/Cordova Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development), which helped me resolve the issue by adding the Android SDK tools and platform-tools directories to the path.