# Phonegap I can't add android platform to my project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I installed Android SDK and $PATH already. But It can't add android platform to my project.
Help me please.

This is my $PATH

```
/Users/xxx/Applications/eclipse/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/xxx/Applications/eclipse/sdk/tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

This is ERROR when I add android platform to my project

```
    Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.
    at /Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:85:29
    at _rejected (/Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /Users/xxx/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576704/phonegap-cordova-android-development?rq=1) would help.

Comment: let me know so I can assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Create file .bash_profile and save in your home directory.

[image]

Then you copy this script into this file.

```
export PATH="/Applications/android-sdk/tools:/Applications/android-sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

Comment: Sorry I use MAC.

It doesn't open SDK manager when I type "android". I think problem is PATH. But I don't know why. How to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can use it. I only change directory of sdk and set again.

Comment: so your problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed something,

To check the SDK just open Command Prompt and type in "`android`" and make sure it opens the SDK manager and check out you have installed the android latest version.

Here is my path and is perfectly configured for phonegap and integrated with eclipse,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\lib;
F:\Phonegap\windows_adt\sdk\platform-tools;F:\Phonegap\windows_adt\sdk\tools;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Here are the sublinks,

```
ANDROID_HOME: F:\Phonegap\windows_adt\sdk
ANT_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\ANT\apache-ant-1.9.2
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
```

Comment: Sorry I use MAC.

It doesn't open SDK manager when I type "android". I think problem is PATH. But I don't know why. How to fix it.

Comment: simply type in 'phonegap' or 'cordova' to verify phonegap installed. Add the sudo command with the existing command for MAC. eg, $sudo npm install -g phonegap
$phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$phonegap local build android.